# Django accessing reverse foreign key data in values object

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

I'm building an CMS for fun but I'm stuck in django when querying resources for a given post.

I have the following code doing what I want:

```
data = list(Post.objects.filter(topic__name=topic_name).values())
for d in data:
    d["resources"] = list(Resource.objects.filter(post=d["id"]).values())
```

The problem is that after selecting the list of posts with a topic in 1 query, it creates 1 more query for each list of resources. Is there a more efficient way to get the dictionary of resources into each post?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(topic__name=topic_name).prefetch_related('resources') # resources is the related_name defined for Post in Resource model
```